# How to deploy multiple web apps on a single IP by script?

Tags: passenger, subdirectory

I have a web service that allows users to create their own web apps. They click a button and a web app gets deployed on my domain.

How can I deploy web apps on a subdomain or sub-uri by script when the user "clicks the button"? Say I have "www.service.com", and I want user created apps to be deployed on "www.service.com/app1", "www.service.com/app2", etc.

Thanks

Comment: Place each application in every newly created folder named by pattern.

Comment: If you don't like idea to place all webapps directly in www-root you can use Alias and Rewrite rules in apache config

Comment: Could link me to an example of using Alias and Rewrite rules in Apache config?

Comment: Also, how would I place each application in a new folder if I used Phusion Passenger? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks that you mentioned Phusion Passenger. It is key point of question. Please look there https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/deploy/ruby/ You need "Deploying an app to a sub-URI or subdirectory" paragraph